# tcolorbox - Define a macro for the title that can be empty

Tags: tcolorbox

I fail to use a macro that give a possibly empty title for a `tcolorbox` frame.

[image]

Here is the code used.

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\def\thistitle{One title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\def\thistitle{}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title = {}]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}
        
\end{document}
```

Comment: There should be sth. with `IfNoValueTF={\thistitle}{true}{false}`  (tcolorbox manual, p. 448), but I don't get it at this moment.

Comment: I can't make the examples work. I thinks I will use a homade wrapper but I was hoping to find an "easy-to-use" solution...

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You should read the section about `pgfkeys` in the [TikZ & PGF manual](http://mirrors.ctan.org/graphics/pgf/base/doc/pgfmanual.pdf). `.expand once` as well as `.expanded` can solve the problem here, since you want to obtain the same as `title={}` when the expansion of `\thistitle` is empty (`.expand once` is in my opinion a better choice than `.expanded` here, since it doesn't expand more than necessary).

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\thistitle}{One title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title/.expand once = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\thistitle}{}
\begin{tcolorbox}[title/.expand once = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[title = {}]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is another way using `etoolbox` and a custom `mytitle` key. It works differently from the previous technique in that it *never feeds any expansion of `\thistitle` to `title`*. The `title` key is either called with `\thistitle`, or not called at all.

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tcolorbox}
\usepackage{etoolbox}

\tcbset{mytitle/.code={%
  \expandafter\ifstrempty\expandafter{\thistitle}
    {}
    {\pgfkeysalso{title=\thistitle}}%
}}

\begin{document}

\newcommand{\thistitle}{One title}
\begin{tcolorbox}[mytitle = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\renewcommand{\thistitle}{}
\begin{tcolorbox}[mytitle = \thistitle]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\begin{tcolorbox}[mytitle = {}]
    Bla, bla, bla....
\end{tcolorbox}

\end{document}
```

Same output as above.

Comment: Ok, this is way easier then the xparse-stuff. ;)

Comment: @cis Yep. But realize that since with `title=\thistitle`, the `title`  key doesn't “see” that `\thistitle` is empty, one can infer that no expandable emptiness test `\foo` would give a better result when used as `title=\foo{\thistitle}`. `title` just doesn't expand its argument by itself, which is good in case it might contain stuff that should only be expanded at the very last moment, when doing the typesetting.

Comment: @cis I've added another way, in case you're interested.

Comment: @frougon Thanks for the `.expand once`. Your homemade solution allows to add materials automatically to the title. This is very intersting !

Comment: @projetmbc Yes, you could even parse the 1st-level expansion of `\thistitle` using regular expressions as provided by the `l3regex` module of `expl3` if you want... or for simpler things, `\str_case:...` and its sisters.